# Android service - intent doesn't update on rebind

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service

I have an `Activity B` which I start and stop every now and then. Whenever I start `B` it will **bind** to a `Service` which is started from the `MainActivity` and which will be **unbound** when leaving `B`.

Everytime I show `B` again it will bind the `Service` like this :

```
    Intent musicIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
    Bundle musicBundle = new Bundle();
    musicBundle.putStringArrayList("playlist", pathList);
    musicBundle.putInt("position", position);

    musicIntent.putExtras(musicBundle);
    getApplicationContext().bindService(musicIntent, mConnection,
            BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

So either `onBind()` or `onRebind()` will be called.

**The Service :**

```
@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    super.onRebind(intent);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    this.songPathList = extras.getStringArrayList("playlist"); //Is always the same
    this.position = extras.getInt("position"); //Is always the same
    this.isInitialzed = false; 
}
```

However, the first time I bind the service and pass some data to it, it's kind of final. The intent's data will never change. So when `onRebind()` gets called the intent will not change `position` and `songPathList`.

To be more clear, I call B and pass some data through an intent for the first time. `position` will be set to 5 and `songPathList` to some random 5 Strings.

Now I leave `B` and start it again. This time `onRebind()` will be called. But this time `position` and `songPathList` have different values than before. But when I debug and check the values in the `onRebind()` they haven't changed. `position` is still **5**.

What did I do wrong? Does anyone know why the intents never change?

And yes, when I start `B` again `position` has a different value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have proof, but I believe that if the only difference between two `Intents` is the extras, the old one will be reused, rather than creating a new `Intent` object.

I know that this is the case with `PendingIntent`s, not sure if it's also the case with regular old `Intent`s.

I've gotten around this limitation with `PendingIntent`s by updating the `requestCode` in the `PendingIntent`, so that there is something clearly different.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some researches I have an answer.

From "Android Developers" documentation:

> ```
> public void onRebind (Intent intent)
> ```
>
> Called when new clients have connected to the service, after it had previously been notified that all had disconnected in its onUnbind(Intent). This will only be called if the implementation of onUnbind(Intent) was overridden to return true.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *intent*   The Intent that was used to bind to this service, as given to Context.bindService. ***Note that any extras that were included with the Intent at that point will not be seen here.***

So as we can see - we should not pass any data along with bind intent.

I really don't know why it is done this way. My solution is to create public method in Service to acces it after service was bound to activity and call these method in *onServiceConnected* method of your mConnection:

In Your service:

```
...
private int position;
private List pathLish;

public void setData(int position, List pathList){
    this.position = position;
    this.pathList = pathList;
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Linked Chat Id now "+chatId);
}
```

In Your activity:

```
 private Boolean bound = false;

 private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        MusicServce.mBinder binder = (MusicServce.mBinder) service;
        musicService= binder.getService();
        musicService.setData(position, pathList);
        bound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        bound = false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent musicIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
    bindService(musicIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```